# CPU Cooling System Making Noise

Tags: cpu, clicking-sound, water-cooling

**Scenario**

I've had this computer for a couple of years and this is the first time I've heard it make any noise. I had it shipped from NYC to UT so there was a large elevation change and I suspect that may be part of the underlying issue.

[YouTube video of the clicking noise](https://youtu.be/t97-A_jZ73M)

**Question**

What's going on here and How to I fix this issue?

*Cheers*

Comment: Seems obvious you should replace what appears to be an AIO cooler

Comment: Atmospheric pressure is less at higher altitudes therefore gasses expand such as any air bubbles in the tubes. The following may be helpful, although you probably want to replenish with fluid designed for the cooler instead of water. https://youtu.be/ElYtpezZASU

Comment: You may need to take it out and refer to either of these videos to make sure your orientation is correct, and to remove the air bubbles. [JayzTwoCents AIO Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKwA7ygTJn0&t=739s) [Corsair Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GcSDODt528)